# Fullscreen video background html5

Tags: html, html5-video

I've read through every post there is about html5 fullscreen video here at stackoverflow. And the best example that keeps on coming up is http://www.html5-fullscreen-video.com .. And it's a beautiful solution.. But it's missing the full description on how to implement it..

Look at the bottom of this page..
http://www.html5-fullscreen-video.com/html5_fullscreen/tutorial/fullscreen_solutions/18

Does anyone have the solution?

Big thanks!

Comment: I had the same problem, would like to find the missing text as well. I am currently playing around with http://www.georgepaterson.com/sandbox/jquery-html5-video-background-demo/ instead, which looks like it could be perfect for my needs.

Comment: Really nice! I read some on the link you sent, does it resize the video when you resize the browser? The link you sent, the video doesn't resize.. same size.

Comment: Depends on the browser. I think it will only work for Chrome and Firefox, and the rest will just see a background image. I am playing around with it at the moment and so far in Firefox and Chrome it's fine, firefox was messing it up if you resized it quickly, but hopefully a user won't be doing this.

Comment: Thanks! The video in the background is big because it's being stretched realtive.. And it runs down through the site. Can it be fixed in the background? Thanks for all your info!

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean, do you want a full screen video at the top with content underneath which you can scroll down to?